# How to fix 301 Redirect for this URL

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I'm trying to transfer over

```
www.old.example/ecards/birthday-ecards/all
```

which no longer exists to

```
https://www.new.example/static-ecards/company-birthday-ecards.html
```

When using `.htaccess` to complete this I'm getting it redirecting to

```
https://www.new.example/static-ecards/company-birthday-ecards.htmlecards/birthday-ecards/all
```

So it's adding this to the end of the URL `ecards/birthday-ecards/all` which is not needed.

I'm a noob with this and not a dev! Please advise.

I have tried

```
Redirect 301 "/old-folder/" "http://www.new.example/new-page.html"

Redirect 301 "/old-page.html" "http://www.new.example/new-page.html"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This probably is what you are looking for:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?old\.example$
RewriteRule ^/?ecards/birthday-ecards/all$ https://www.new.example/static-ecards/company-birthday-ecards.html [R=301]
```

It is a good idea to start out with a 302 temporary redirection and only change that to a 301 permanent redirection later, once you are certain everything is correctly set up. That prevents caching issues while trying things out...

This rule will work likewise in the http servers host configuration or inside a dynamic configuration file (".htaccess" file). Obviously the rewriting module needs to be loaded inside the http server and enabled in the http host. In case you use a dynamic configuration file you need to take care that it's interpretation is enabled at all in the host configuration and that it is located in the host's `DOCUMENT_ROOT` folder.

And a general remark: you should always prefer to place such rules in the http servers host configuration instead of using dynamic configuration files (".htaccess"). Those dynamic configuration files add complexity, are often a cause of unexpected behavior, hard to debug and they really slow down the http server. They are only provided as a last option for situations where you do not have access to the real http servers host configuration (read: really cheap service providers) or for applications insisting on writing their own rules (which is an obvious security nightmare).

Answer (score 1):

Add this rule on top of `old.example` .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^ecards/birthday-ecards/all$ https://www.new.example/static-ecards/company-birthday-ecards.html [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Hi Jarek, Thanks for such a prompt reply, this did not work and still redirects to the same page?